# "The server was unable to save the form at this Time. Please try again." 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, error, 403

I am experiencing an issue with SharePoint 2016 server that when I want to create a new List I am getting this error.
From ULS log

> Begin CSOM Request
>
> Request is a Cross-Origin request. Origin is : 'domain.com' Host is : 'app server IP'
>
> Request is a Cross-Origin request for a user that was not authenticated using OAuth. Returning 403
>
> The alternate access mapping is configured correctly.

I have tried absolutely everything from Google and this site like RAM, restart etc. but nothing works.

Also the issue only persists when I am opening SharePoint from domain name  (URL Rewrite, Web forward server).

If I access the SharePoint locally from the server machine It works greatly.
I am using URL Rewrite and Proxy Forward and I think there is some issue with it but also I tried everything even the AI ChatGPT bot but still no luck.

Any tips?

Comment: Have you configured your alternative access mappings correctly? Not sure why you would need the URL rewrite.

Comment: Hello, Yes It is configured correctly as I checked it multiple times. URL Rewrite is needed because of the DNS.

Comment: Your rewrite is causing the problem, the domain needs to be configured as part of your AAM rather than rewriting the URL to use the domain you wish. It's in the error message.

Comment: The Domain is also written in AAM. The Web is accessible but I can not create or save anything on there.

Comment: If the domain is already configured in the AAM, why do you need the URL rewrite?

Comment: URL Rewrite is actualy a module in IIS that is reverse proxy to my sharepoint server. 
I have to have presentation layer (Web Server) to access the Application Server (SharePoint).

Comment: Why would you do that? SharePoint server has a web front end role for this very purpose e.g. you can have multiple SP servers in a farm with different roles.

Comment: We just have a single farm. It is needed duo to some policies.

Comment: Do you mean single server? You can have multiple servers in your farm. Surely the URL rewrite is only needed to change the URL from what SharePoint is currently using, that will cause a cross-origin problem.